# $.post returning (empty string)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to populate a table using jQuery `$.post`, but I keep getting `(an empty string)` when I log the data using firebugs `console.log()`, here is the code,

jQuery:

```
        $.each(data, function(i, json){
            //get the system names
            $.post('get_system_name.php', {product_id:json.product_id}, function(data){

                console.log(data);

            });             
        });
```

PHP:

```
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "1234") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("eskom_products") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT products FROM products WHERE product_id='".$product_id."'") or die(mysql_error('Please try again'));
$array = mysql_fetch_array($query, true);

echo $array['products'] ;
```

Initially I do a `$.getJSON()` request, and then I loop through all of the entries I get back using `$.each`, but as you can see, the name of the system is not in the same table, so I need to do a seperate `$.post()` to get the name in the related table, but all I get is an empty string, any ideas?

Comment: This can have any number of reasons - basic debugging is the key. E.g. activate `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the script to see whether there's any problems with the syntax

Comment: Also, you have a SQL injection vulnerability in the PHP script (you need to escape the `product_id` parameter)

Comment: this may not be relevant, but just curious though, why are you calling several post to the server when you can do it just once?

Comment: @jerjer, from the OP's description he appears to be avoiding a JOIN in his SQL query.

Comment: did you mean to return JSON from PHP? echo json_encode($array['products']);

Comment: Thanx guys, got it to work, I changed it over to `$.get` and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear your jquery is ok, the only problem would be the value of json.product_id, that could be wrong, but I suppose it's not the problem.

Verify the database is returning something. To do that, access directly to "get_system_name.php?product_id="+PRODUCTID (change this). And change the $_POST for a $_REQUEST or $_GET.

In this way you jump the javascript step.

Comment: I cnahged it to `$.get` and that did the trick, just adjusted the PHP code accordingly, thanx!

Comment: @user270311 - it's nice to give the right answer, but the way you say you did (change everything to get), does not explain why it was wrong. Did you find any mistake?